# Trying to display images from a website in Android

Tags: android, image

below is my code... but only a blank screen shows up, anyone know what's up?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://pennapps.com/biblioteka/images/C.jpg");
            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(bm);
            setContentView(image);
        } 



        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the logs, it's tough to say, but a common pitfall is forgetting to request the INTERNET permission.  In addition, it's highly recommended that you do not make web requests on the main (UI) thread.  There is an excellent article on [Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) that also covers the topic of image downloading.

Comment: Yes, requasting the INTERNET permission makes that code work. Doing it in a different thread remains an excellent idea.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the permission tag , else the code seems to be working